# Use of the word "lore"

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Should I use the word [*lore*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lore) when speaking about knowledge that is connected to a specific domain, or would it be better to use the expression "professional knowledge"?

Comment: *Lore* usually refers to the collective wisdom of a group that is passed on by word of mouth. You are better off just using *knowledge*. You can also refer to *domain knowledge* in that respect.

Comment: On Merriam-Webster "lore: knowledge gained through study or experience".

Comment: *professional knowledge* is much more formal than *lore,* but in an informal setting, I would think *lore* is just as good.

Comment: *Lore* has the connotation of being less than authoritative, anecdotal. This might be because of the related word *folklore*, which has as a definition "A body of **popular myths and beliefs** relating to a particular place, activity, or group of people."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean. If you're suggesting that the knowledge is based mostly on tradition, rather than on evidence, then *lore* might be a good choice, but in most cases, *professional knowledge* would be the best choice.